# How to echo function name on Laravel blade

Tags: laravel

my function is

```
 public function testfunction(){
        return view('back.page.simple');

    }
```

my blade template is "simple"
i will try dispaly function name in my simple blade file. how to get function name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function testfunction(){
    $functionName = "testfunction";
    return view('back.page.simple', compact('functionName'));
 }
```

And in blade you will access name like this:

```
<p>{{ isset($functionName) ? $functionName : "Your default text" }}</p>
```

Do you look for this solution ?